# why is my ajax function not working and it is throwing exception for data objects to be not defined?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax

I am trying to call ajax query in my code but it is not working. I have common header and footer (php) for all other files. It is returning the required data but showing inside html code. I tried and searched everywhere but couldn't get through this.
I am really sorry for not posting code here because i tried for an hour to post code but i couldn't as this editor was giving an error about code not formatted.

Html Part of code

```
<div class="form-group">
    <select class="selectpicker" data-live-search="true" data-style="form-control"
           name="" id="sale_customer" required>
                                 
    </select>
</div>

<div class="row cus-note">
    <p class="note-field col-6" id="note_customer" name="search"> </p>
    <textarea type="text" class="form-control note-field col-6" name="" value=""
              placeholder="New Note..." required></textarea>
</div>
```

JQuery Part

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

    function loadCustomer(notes, cust) {
    // console.log("cust");
        $.ajax({
           url: "<?php echo $folder;?>crud.php",
           type: "POST",
           data: {
               note: notes,
               customer: cust
           },
           success: function(data) {
               if (data.note == "notes") {
       // alert('haaalp');
                   $("#note_customer").html(data);
               } else {
                      $("#sale_customer").append(data);
       alert('haaalp');
               }

           }
       });
   }

   loadCustomer("noteD","");

   $("#sale_customer").on("change", function() {
    var customer = $("#sale_customer").val();
    console.log(customer);

    if (customer != "") {
        loadCustomer("notes", customer);
    }
    else {
        $("#note_customer").html("");
    }
});


});
</script>
```

Server Side Code

```
if($_POST['note'] == "noteD"){
   $sql = "SELECT * FROM customer";

   $query = mysqli_query($db, $sql) or die("Query Unsuccessful.");

   $sale_customer = "<option selected value='wic'><sub>test</sub></option>";
   while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)){
     $sale_customer .= "<option value='{$row['name']}'>{$row['name']}</option>";
   }
   echo $sale_customer;    
}
else if($_POST['note'] == "notes"){

    $customer = $_POST['customer'];
    $query = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM customer WHERE name = 'Ali'") or die("Query 
    Unsuccessful.");

    $sale_customer = "";
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)){
    $sale_customer .= "{$row['note']}";
}
echo $sale_customer;
}
```

I can see successfully returned data in console. it is also gong inside condition but not displaying in selector. and in if condition if use only note instead of `data.note` it throws exception that `note` is not defined..

[Ajax code for successful return](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7uYuN.png)

[Data returned on console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DnPbC.png)

[data.note to only note](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DXewO.png)

[note object not found](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tlXQ6.png)

Comment: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: I appreciate it but I really tried so hard to paste code but every time there occurred error of code not formatted however the code was formatted well .after 1 hour of trying i had to post pictures. I really am sorry for that but this problem is killing me.

Comment: Ha, it's alright then. There is a "format code" button in the text editor, and also a "Code snippet button". Worse case scenario, just edit your question, paste your code, and then I'll format it for you

Comment: In one case you return html and in the other you return improperly formatted JSON

Comment: because this is conditioned base.

Answer (score 1):

Hurrah!!!

After searching here and there I found a solution to overcome this issue.
The main problem was the bootstrap selectpicker. The ajax was returning the data but select was not showing it. In

```
success: function(data) {
            if (note == "notes") {
                $("#note_customer").html(data);
            } else {
                $("#sale_customer").append(data);
            }

        }
```

I just added `$("#sale_customer").append(data).selectpicker('refresh');`

and it worked but again the other issue preserved that in `if (note == "notes") {` "`note`" is not defined.
for that purpose I took 2 variables outside ajax as `var note = notes;`, `var customer = cust;` and then posted in data object as

```
data: {
            note,
            customer
        },
```

and the result occurred which was expected.

The issue was with bootstrap selectpicker and data objects.